How to change gravity? official documentation is not working
The example from the official documentation is not working when adding it to ServerScriptService
https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/DataModel
local Workspace = game:GetService("Workspace")

Workspace.Gravity = 20


What script is this in (LocalScript, ModuleScript, Script) and where is that script (Workspace, ServerScriptService, StarterPlayerScripts, etc)?

The code works, you should double check that your code is executing. Here are some sanity checks to make sure that your Script is actually firing :

Is this a Script, and not a LocalScript or ModuleScript.
Is this Script in a location where it will execute? It must be a descendant of the Workspace, or ServerScriptService. It's always good to double check that it is not in ServerStorage by accident.
Is the Script's Enabled property set to True
Is the Script's Run-Context property set to Server
If I put a print("Hello World") in the Script, does it show up in the Output?

